# Exporting Chart Throws RangeError: Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded in highcharts-more.js

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a series of packedbubble charts. One of them throws the RangeError in title when I try and export the graph. Others do not. The chart builder is the same for all the graphs just the data and title text appended to chart upon export.

I have a live demo up [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nw5rj46o/).
Pertinent code here:

```
function assetCirclePack(targetDiv, dataset, labelfilter, useSimulationBool, exportURL, NoDataString) {
    var chartCirclePack = Highcharts.chart(targetDiv, {
        chart: {
            type: 'packedbubble',
            events: {
                click: function (event) {
                    clearSelectedHighlight();
                }
            }
        },
        lang: {
            noData: NoDataString
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        exporting: {
            url: exportURL
        },
        colors: ['rgb(166,206,227)', 'rgb(31,120,180)', 'rgb(178,223,138)', 'rgb(51,160,44)', 'rgb(251,154,153)', 'rgb(227,26,28)', 'rgb(253,191,111)', 'rgb(255,127,0)', 'rgb(202,178,214)', 'rgb(106,61,154)', 'rgb(255,255,153)', 'rgb(177,89,40)', 'rgb(141,211,199)', 'rgb(255,255,179)', 'rgb(190,186,218)', 'rgb(251,128,114)', 'rgb(128,177,211)', 'rgb(253,180,98)', 'rgb(179,222,105)', 'rgb(252,205,229)', 'rgb(217,217,217)', 'rgb(188,128,189)', 'rgb(204,235,197)', 'rgb(255,237,111)'],
        legend: {
            enabled: true,
            maxHeight: 107
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            pointFormat: '<b>{point.name}:</b> {point.value}</sub>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                lineWidth: 0,
                events: {
                    click: function (event) {
                        chartPointClick(event.point.idx);
                    }
                }
            },
            packedbubble: {
                minSize: '5%',
                maxSize: '100%',
                useSimulation: false,
                layoutAlgorithm: {
                    gravitationalConstant: 0.01,
                    splitSeries: true,
                    seriesInteraction: true,
                    dragBetweenSeries: false,
                    parentNodeLimit: true
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.name}',
                    filter: {
                        property: 'y',
                        operator: '>',
                        value: labelfilter
                    },
                    style: {
                        color: 'black',
                        textOutline: 'none',
                        fontWeight: 'normal'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: dataset
    });
};

function clearSelectedHighlight() {
    var chartArray = Highcharts.charts;

    for (var i = 0; i < chartArray.length; i++) {
        var thechart = Highcharts.charts[i];
        if (typeof thechart !== 'undefined') {
            if (thechart.types[0] !== 'map') {
                for (var j = 0; j < thechart.series.length; j++) {
                    var theData = thechart.series[j].data;

                    if (thechart.renderTo.tagName == 'DIV') {
                        if (thechart.types[0] == 'packedbubble') {
                            for (var d = 0; d < theData.length; d++) {
                                //thechart.pointer.reset();
                            }
                        } else {
                            for (var d = 0; d < theData.length; d++) {
                                theData[d].update({
                                    color: Highcharts.Color(theData[d].color).setOpacity(1).get()
                                }, true);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (thechart.renderTo.tagName == 'TD') {
                        theSeries.update({
                            color: Highcharts.Color(theSeries.color).setOpacity(1).get()
                        }, true);
                    }

                    thechart.pointer.reset();
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}

function chartPointClick(pointidx) {
    var chartArray = Highcharts.charts;
    for (var i = 0; i < chartArray.length; i++) {
        var thechart = Highcharts.charts[i];
        if (typeof thechart !== 'undefined') {
            if (thechart.types[0] !== 'map') {
                thechart.pointer.reset();

                for (var j = 0; j < thechart.series.length; j++) {
                    var theData = thechart.series[j].data;

                    if (thechart.renderTo.tagName == 'DIV') {
                        if (thechart.types[0] == 'packedbubble') {
                            for (var d = 0; d < theData.length; d++) {
                                if (theData[d].idx != pointidx) {
                                    //theData[d].setState();
                                } else {
                                    theData[d].setState('hover');
                                    thechart.tooltip.refresh(theData[d]);
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            for (var d = 0; d < theData.length; d++) {
                                if (theData[d].idx != pointidx) {
                                    theData[d].update({
                                        color: Highcharts.Color(theData[d].color).setOpacity(0.3).get()
                                    }, true);
                                } else {
                                    theData[d].update({
                                        color: Highcharts.Color(theData[d].color).setOpacity(1).get()
                                    }, true);
                                    thechart.tooltip.refresh(theData[d]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (thechart.renderTo.tagName == 'TD') {
                        var theSeries = thechart.series[j]
                        if (theSeries.options.idx != pointidx) {
                            theSeries.update({
                                color: Highcharts.Color(theSeries.color).setOpacity(0.3).get()
                            }, true);
                        } else {
                            theSeries.update({
                                color: Highcharts.Color(theSeries.color).setOpacity(1).get()
                            }, true);
                            thechart.tooltip.refresh([theSeries.points[0]]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function chartExportSwitch(chartid, exportSelect, graphHeader, graphFooter, marginSize) {
    var type = 'image/jpeg';

    switch ($(exportSelect).val()) {
        case 'JPEG':
            type = 'image/jpeg';
            break;
        case 'PNG':
            type = 'image/png';
            break;
        case 'SVG':
            type = 'image/svg+xml';
            break;
        case 'PDF':
            type = 'application/pdf';
            break;
    }

    chartExportLoc(chartid, type, graphHeader, graphFooter, marginSize);

    $(exportSelect).slideToggle('fast');
}

function chartExportLoc(chartid, exportType, graphHeader, graphFooter, marginSize) {
    if (!marginSize) {
        marginSize = 15;    //HighCharts default
    }

    var chart = $('#' + chartid).highcharts();

    if (chartid == "chartDisthcmap") {
        chart.exportChart(
            { type: exportType, scale: 1, allowHTML: true },
            {
                title: { text: unescape(encodeURI(graphHeader)), margin: marginSize },
                subtitle: { y: 10, text: unescape(encodeURI(graphFooter)) },
                chart: { shadow: false, width: 800 }
            });

        return false;
    }

    if (chartid == "chartStock") {
        chart.exportChart(
            { type: exportType, scale: 1, allowHTML: true },
            {
                title: { text: unescape(encodeURI(graphHeader)), margin: marginSize, useHTML: true },
                legend: { y: -6 },
                subtitle: { y: 3, text: unescape(encodeURI(graphFooter)), useHTML: true },
                chart: { spacingBottom: 35, shadow: false, height: 1.1 * chart.chartHeight, width: 800 },
            });

        return false;
    }

    if (chartid == "chartMain" || chartid == "chartScatterPlot" || chartid == "chartCirclePack") {
        chart.exportChart(
            { type: exportType, scale: 1 },
            {
                title: { text: unescape(encodeURI(graphHeader)), margin: marginSize },
                subtitle: { text: unescape(encodeURI(graphFooter)) },
                chart: {
                    shadow: false,
                    width: 800
                }
            });

        return false;
    }

    if (chartid == "chartDist") {
        chart.exportChart(
            { type: exportType, scale: 1, allowHTML: true },
            {
                title: { text: unescape(encodeURI(graphHeader)), margin: marginSize, useHTML: true },
                subtitle: { y: 10, text: unescape(encodeURI(graphFooter)), useHTML: true },
                chart: { shadow: false, width: 800 }
            });

        return false;
    }

    return false;
}


$(document).ready(function(){ assetCirclePack('chartCirclePack', [{name: 'Employment', data: [{name: 'Architecture and Engineering', value: 64360, idx: 170000},{name: 'Arts, Design, Entertainment, Sports, and Media', value: 42060, idx: 270000},{name: 'Building and Grounds Cleaning and Maintenance', value: 131100, idx: 370000},{name: 'Business and Financial Operations', value: 213810, idx: 130000},{name: 'Community and Social Services', value: 51520, idx: 210000},{name: 'Computer and Mathematical', value: 129080, idx: 150000},{name: 'Construction and Extraction', value: 157810, idx: 470000},{name: 'Education, Training, and Library', value: 277250, idx: 250000},{name: 'Farming, Fishing, and Forestry', value: 8220, idx: 450000},{name: 'Food Preparation and Serving Related', value: 421170, idx: 350000},{name: 'Healthcare Practitioners and Technical', value: 264860, idx: 290000},{name: 'Healthcare Support', value: 147990, idx: 310000},{name: 'Installation, Maintenance, and Repair', value: 182490, idx: 490000},{name: 'Legal', value: 21570, idx: 230000},{name: 'Life, Physical, and Social Science', value: 34940, idx: 190000},{name: 'Management', value: 183580, idx: 110000},{name: 'Office and Administrative Support', value: 631920, idx: 430000},{name: 'Personal Care and Service', value: 113420, idx: 390000},{name: 'Production', value: 340210, idx: 510000},{name: 'Protective Service', value: 99920, idx: 330000},{name: 'Sales and Related', value: 461060, idx: 410000},{name: 'Transportation and Material Moving', value: 320050, idx: 530000}]}
], 274152.5, false, 'https://export.highccharts.com', 'No data to display'); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that your current problem is related to the size of your exported chart's plot area when such long text is set to both Title and Subtitle. Because of this text, there is not enough space for bubbles to render which cause an error.

What I recommend is to change height of your exported chart so it will have enough space for bubbles to render.

```
chart: {
    shadow: false,
    width: 800,
    height: 1000
}
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/y7w1sbak/

Comment: That and the fact that I had items in other data sets like `..., idx: 31-33,...` Loving federal taxonomies right now. I fell into a trap of my own making.